# RabbitMQ Management Plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I am having some issues accessing the rabbitmq_management plugin.
I am running RabbitMQ 3.6.2, where rabbit is installed as a service and the plugin is enabled. Running on Windows Microsoft Server 2012.

Service runs fine, no errors in logs, however when i try and access the management tool via the web browser UI, "This page can't be displayed", I am sure i am going to the right port as the logs show the port it is running on, i have tried adding some rules to the Inbound on the firewall in case it was to do with ports and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

EDIT

I am able to access the port via another machine on the network but does still not work in local host.

Comment: try using telnet to check the port. Does it work in local host ?

Comment: I will try using telnet, and no it does not work in local host.